# Gensim returns "ValueError: input must have more than one sentence" in for loop through list of paragraphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, for-loop, gensim

I'm trying to use gensim `summarize()` to simplify paragraphs in job descriptions.
I webscraped a bunch of job descriptions using the selenium package and stored them in a list.

```
descriptions=[]
for link in job_urls:
    driver.get(link)
    jd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="jobDescriptionText"]').text
    #The form element with attribute id set to jobDescriptionText
    descriptions.append(jd)
```

[The output is a list of text; each item is multiple paragraphs.  EX:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXRFc.jpg)

If I summarize item one at a time with an index, the code works.:

```
    text = descriptions[2] # Change index to desired job description.
    summarize(str(text), ratio=0.5)
'The core function of this opening is to conduct regional studies and mapping.\nAs the successful candidate you would be expected to conduct regional exploration studies and evaluations of the petroleum system elements, and possess the experience to integrate geological and geophysical data to create regional maps.\nYou should have the aptitude for, and tireless energy around data mining and analysis, with high level computer mapping skills.\nMinimum Requirements\nYou will be required to perform the following:\nConduct regional exploration studies and evaluations of the petroleum system elements, and integrate available geological and geophysical data to create regional maps.\nDevelop gross depositional environment maps, effectiveness maps, common risk segment maps of all petroleum system elements (source, reservoir seal), and composite common risk segment maps of different plays, to develop new play concepts and exploration opportunities.\nAnalyze data mining with high level of computer mapping skills, using major Exploration software packages, preferably Petrel.'
```

But if I loop through the list, the function throws the ValueError:

```
for text in descriptions:
    text = str(text)
    summarize(text, ratio=0.5)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-b3969fcb2610> in <module>
      4 for text in descriptions:
      5     text = str(text)
----> 6     summarize(text, ratio=0.5)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\summarization\summarizer.py in summarize(text, ratio, word_count, split)
    426     # If only one sentence is present, the function raises an error (Avoids ZeroDivisionError).
    427     if len(sentences) == 1:
--> 428         raise ValueError("input must have more than one sentence")
    429 
    430     # Warns if the text is too short.
ValueError: input must have more than one sentence
```

And with a list comprehension:

```
summary = [summarize(str(text),ratio=0.5) for text in descriptions]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-8d79c7c19d53> in <module>
      1 #text = descriptions[2] # Change index to desired job description.
      2 #summarize(str(text), ratio=0.5)
----> 3 summary = [summarize(str(text),ratio=0.5) for text in descriptions]
      4 #for text in descriptions:
      5    # print(str(text)+"\n")

<ipython-input-31-8d79c7c19d53> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 #text = descriptions[2] # Change index to desired job description.
      2 #summarize(str(text), ratio=0.5)
----> 3 summary = [summarize(str(text),ratio=0.5) for text in descriptions]
      4 #for text in descriptions:
      5    # print(str(text)+"\n")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\summarization\summarizer.py in summarize(text, ratio, word_count, split)
    426     # If only one sentence is present, the function raises an error (Avoids ZeroDivisionError).
    427     if len(sentences) == 1:
--> 428         raise ValueError("input must have more than one sentence")
    429 
    430     # Warns if the text is too short.

ValueError: input must have more than one sentence
```

The items are more than one sentence and `summarize()` works individually.  Why would `summarize()` throw this error in a loop or list comprehension?

Comment: "for loop" != " list comprehension". Did you try to use `for` loop?

Comment: same error but without <listcomp>(.0) section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, a day later I figured it out.  As gojomo mentioned, there was a job description with only one sentence (who does that?).  I was able to catch it with some exploration of character length and watching the web driver webscrape.

To debug use:

```
for i, text in enumerate(descriptions):
        try:
            summarize(text, ratio=0.5)
        except:
            print("Job description {} could not be summarized".format(i))
            continue
```

Lesson learned: don't assume all job descriptions have more than one sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `summarization` module will be removed from the next Gensim release:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#11-removed-gensimsummarization

(It was quite idiosyncratic in its approach, hard-to-generalize, and without any active maintenance.)

That said, if you're getting the error "input must have more than one sentence", you're probably feeding it an input of just one sentence – or at least, something that looks like a single sentence to its very-crude sentence-splitter.

Have you tried printing the `text` values that specifically trigger this error, to verify that they have more than one sentence?

Comment: Thanks for the head's up! I'm new to nlp and exploring its options. Referencing your comment [link](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2592), "They look for something else entirely," do you have alternative summarization packages you would recommend? I've used nltk.tokenize and that's about it

Comment: Alas, I don't offhand know any more robust/flexible summarization code.